# How to represent CSS class in SASS language?

Tags: css, sass

How to represent this in SASS language

```
.solo:hover > .solo-pane, .solo-pane.active, .solo-pane.lighten
{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I'm facing problem with seperating the classes with (,) comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straight forward. Nest it where comma separated things are on the same level.

**SASS**

```
.solo:hover > .solo-pane
  opacity: 0.5

.solo-pane
  &.active, &.lighten
    opacity: 0.5
```

**SCSS**

```
.solo:hover > .solo-pane {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.solo-pane {
  &.active, &.lighten {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```